# JasperReports Server Pro - open reports in new browser tab/window

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

In *JasperReports Server Pro 4.5*, is there any way to force the program to open reports/repository elements in a new browser tab or window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to fix that by updating the relevant JavaScript file to force everything to open in a new tab. In JRS 4.5.1 it's line 766 in the file .../jasperserver-pro/scripts/repository.search.actions.js

```js
repositorySearch.RedirectAction.createRunResourceAction = function(resource, inNewTab) {
    if (!resource) {
        resource = resource ? resource : repositorySearch.model.getSelectedResources()[0];
    }

    var factoryMethod = repositorySearch.runActionFactory[resource.typeSuffix()];

    if (factoryMethod) {
        /* return factoryMethod(resource, inNewTab);  this was the original */
        return factoryMethod(resource, true);
    } else {
        return new repositorySearch.Action(function() {
            alert("Run action for resource type '" + resource.resourceType + "' is not implemented!");
        });
    }
};
```

I cannot claim credit for figuring it out. Thanks to Igor Nesterenko for this solution.